# create an awk file to filter out unduplicated lines of a dataset

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I have the following dataset and I would like to implement an iteration that checks line by line(awk or for) in an awk file that after executing it in the following way:

```
gawk -f file.awk dataset.csv
```

Allow me to get a file with the records without duplicates and the float in the last column rounded to two decimals. Below, I attach a sample of my dataset and as you can see there should be only one record per country.

```
40462186,US,177827,7671,4395,190
2872296,US,273870,3492,95349,1216
45236699,US,265691,6874,5873,152
```

Since my level is not advanced, I don't mind if the code is long so I can familiarise myself with the steps the code goes through.

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}' file
```

I found that this command can help in such functionality it would be a shell script in not an awk script.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Good suggestion! I'll do it right away

Comment: Your code seems to print duplicates, not unique lines. As your input seems to be CSV, do you care about line order of output? (except header, of course)

Comment: @jhnc Talking about this, you have made me realise this aspect. And no, I don't care about the order :)

Comment: Your example does not contain duplicate lines. Did I miss something?

Comment: By doing a visual inspection beforehand, I do not see any duplicates at a glance. However, it is an important data cleansing task and this way I can make sure

Comment: I think you're posting stuff about shell script vs awk script in your recent questions because you want to have an awk script saved in a file that you can use `awk -f script.awk file` on. To change a shell script like `awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}' file` into an awk script, just remove `awk '` and `' file`, i.e. remove the part where the shell calls awk to interpret the script and passes it the input file name, to end up with `{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}` and save that in a file named `script.awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a)if (a[i]>1)print i;}' file
```

has the test inverted: `a[i]>1` should be `a[i]==1` to only print unique lines.

Some ways to implement truncation of `n` to 2 decimal places are:

```
n = substr(n,1,match(n,/[.]/)+2)

n = sprintf("%0.2f",n)
```

So your script could be:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } # delimit columns by comma
                     # csv must not have embedded commas

NR==1 {print; next} # print header

{ $10 = sprintf("%0.2f", $10) } # truncate column 10
                                # rewrites $0 so uses OFS

{ a[$0]++ } # using $0 means entire line must be unique

END { for (i in a) if (a[i]==1) print i } # print unique lines
```

---

Given your comment about data cleansing, it would probably be better to use a two-pass approach: use your original code to alert you to erroneous input, then truncate in a separate pass.

Note that if a single column changes you will get what appears to be valid input. These lines are different:

```
Afghanistan,Afghanistan,AFG,40462186,Asia,177827,7671,4395,190,4.313743132
Afghanistan,Afghanistan,AFG,40462106,Asia,177827,7671,4395,190,4.313743132
```

I suppose you wanted to detect this, so your sanity checks need to be more sophisticated.

Comment: I just tried it and I am eternally grateful!!!! Finally, I would appreciate if you could help me to include a functionality in this script which is to make the quotient between "Total Cases" and "Total Deaths" of each record and include a new column with this result. The only thing is that there are cases where "Total Deaths" is equal to 0 (would report error) but in that case indicate 100.

Comment: This new column would be like to calculate the "Survival Percentage" you could say.

Comment: That's a different question.